# Error when sharing a video to Google Photos

Tags: android, video

I managed to make a video sharing dialog which works just fine for every other app but not Google Photos. For some reason, Google Photos shows me the video upload dialog, but after clicking "Upload", I get: "Error, couldn't upload media".

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("video/mp4");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, SHARE_AUTHORITY, resultFile);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

// Tried with these as well:
//shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
//shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");

activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Your Video"));
```

Facebook, Youtube, Gmail etc. all work fine. The video I tried is this one:

http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4

Only Google Photos is not accepting the video, and if I share the same video from e.g. from Google Drive to Google Photos, it works just fine.

Logcat doesn't show anything.

Has anyone got sharing videos to Google Photos working?

Comment: Did you ever find the root cause here? I'm seeing a similar issue with uploading images to Google Photos.

Comment: Unfortunately a solution was never found

Answer (score -1):

Here's one probable cause for this failure: it tries to access the file which is private for your application through the URI and fails as you didn't grant the permission to do that. Here's how you do it:

1. Make sure that the content provider in the manifest has the parameter `android:grantUriPermissions="true"`;
2. Set the clip data by calling `shareIntent.setClipData`. Your data should contain an item with the URI you want to open.
3. Call `shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`.

This will tell Android to look at the URI in the clip data and grant a one-time permission to access it to the application selected by the user.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say that I already had android:grantUriPermissions="true" and also tried with shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION).

With shareIntent.setClipData the Photos share dialog just doesn't even open, but closes silently.

Anything else that could be wrong? I've tried with many other apps and the sharing works just fine, so it's strange if it were a permission issue...

Comment: @EsaTanskanen You need to set clip data because otherwise the permissions won't be given properly. Try launching the activity without the chooser.